# Responsive eDM issue

Tags: responsive-design, html-table, html-email, electronic-direct-mail

I am currently making an eDM for an event coming up for our business. I have used a responsive boilerplate that is intended for this.

It is a two column layout, that folds into a 1 column layout when the device width <600px (using a media query).

[You can see it here](http://hardedgemedia.com/preview/eDMs/The-Hard-Word/june-2015-what-a-girl-wants-what-a-girl-needs)

When I preview it in the browser, it looks great and everything works as intended.
When I view it on my phone (Sony Z2 - **Gmail App**), a few things don't look right. The top black banner isn't full width. The first "Hard Word" section isn't full width, some of the text is purple.

Is this just an issue with the gmail app?

It looks okay using my phone's default email client, and iOS.

Sorry I can't post the code, as it breaks the code element in stack overflow. Sorry. Feel free to inspect the source.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Please see screenshots below

- [Not full width cell](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ac4y9ydce)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with EDMs are they do not support any CSS styles or media queries or what so ever.  As far as I know , using the HTML property width=100% is the only way to make a EDM responsive.